# Linker error while compiling mexfunction with boost

Tags: c++, boost, mex

I'm trying to use boost in mexfunctions.

Given below is my code

**main.cpp**

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>   
#include <boost/date_time.hpp> 

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])

{
    mexPrintf("test boost");

}
```

I compile it using the below command

```
mex main.cpp -LC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64\stage\lib -IC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64
```

Then i get this linking error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_55.lib' 

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'main.mexw64' failed.
```

Then I compiled again using,

```
mex main.cpp -LC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64\stage\lib -IC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64 -llibboost_thread-vc100-mt-s-1_55
```

But still I get the same error. How can I solve this ?

**EDIT :**

I can use boost in a normal visual studio c++ project without any issue. The issue only comes when I put it in a mexfunction

Comment: What linker command is mex running for you?  Perhaps it has a verbose flag to print that.

Comment: I think this is what you are asking. The Command is
errCode = runCmdInShell(cmdtool, cmdargs); where "cmdtool =
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\sys\perl\win32\bin\perl.exe" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\mex.pl" "
and "cmdargs =
-called_from_matlab -matlab "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a"  main.cpp -LC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64\stage\lib -IC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64 -lboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_55"
and the returned errorCode is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old now, but I've had a similar issue with mex and I could solve it by specifying not only the library directory search path, but also the name of the compiled library object.

For that I used the following command:

```
mex main.cpp -I<path/to/lib> -L<path/to/lib/objects> -l<object_name>
```

The command line option `-l` is used to tell mex to link a specified object library. Mex will then try to find whatever is added to `-l` and will append .lib for windows and .LIBEXT for unix.

Here an example with real paths:

```
mex main.cpp -IC:\boost_1_54_0 -LC:\boost_1_54_0\release -lthread
```

And finally in your case I would suggest trying:

```
mex main.cpp -IC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64 -LC:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\10.0\x64\stage\lib -lthread
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed that defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` also helps, because when I remove this define I get the error again.
To define a symbol name you can use the command line option `-D` so just add `-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`